# Need Advice: Laravel single signon for different laravel applications

Tags: laravel, single-sign-on, laravel-5.1

I have a certain requirement where i will have a central laravel application, and it has all the users in there. Then there are 2-3 sub laravel applications. The users are individually given access to these sub applications.

**Now the requirement is that these sub applications shouldn't have any users in there.** They should query the central laravel application (through api).

So if someone signs in the central laravel application, it should automatically sign-in to the other applications that they are given access to.

I am aware that providing code wont be possible, so just an overall overview of how it might work and some packages that might be helpful would be really great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have pretty much done this. I really struggled to find examples/advice so just started building it.

I have several applications, all for internal use.

I have one application/db for storing users/roles/permissions.

In my other applications, the user model just points to the usermanager db.
When user log in, I grab all their permissions for this application and store them in the session.

Seems to be working so far.

Mick